# Cover Trigger Test class totally

Tags: trigger, unit-test

(Hello Guys), How can I cover test class for this trigger? I put already all neccesary data but only I'm getting 55%, the test is ok but I have some hours with this and I don't know what is missing. The test clases is covering 2 triggers, thats why is showing data that there'isnt in my trigger

**Trigger**

```
trigger OpportunityTriggerPopulateFromTemplate on Opportunity (after insert, after update) {    
    if(Trigger.isInsert){
        List<PopulateStage__c> populateStage = [SELECT Stage__c FROM PopulateStage__c];
        String popStage = populateStage[0].Stage__c;

        for(Opportunity opportunity : trigger.new) {
            if(opportunity.RecordTypeId != '0125e000000hxJtAAI' && opportunity.OpportunityTemplate__c != null && opportunity.StageName == popStage && opportunity.PopulateFromTemplate__c==true ){
                opportunity.PopulateFromTemplate__c=false;
                //List<Opportunity> opportunityTemplates = OpportunityTriggerHandler.getOpportunitiesTemplatesFromOpportunity(opportunity);
                Opportunity opportunityTemplate = OpportunityTriggerHandler.getOpportunityTemplateFromOpportunity(opportunity);
                List<OpportunityLineItem> opportunityLineItems = OpportunityTriggerHandler.getOpportunityLineItemsFromTemplate(opportunity.OpportunityTemplate__c);
                OpportunityTriggerHandler.createQuoteFromOpportunityLineItems(opportunityLineItems,opportunity,opportunityTemplate);
                //OpportunityTriggerHandler.addOpportunityLineItems(opportunityLineItems,opportunity);
            }          
        }
    }
}
```

**Test class**

```
@isTest
private class TestOpportunityTriggerHandler {
    @testSetup static void setup() {        
          // Create a Pricebook
        Pricebook2 priceBook = new Pricebook2(
            Name = 'Example Price Book',
            Description = 'This is the Price Book description.',
            IsActive = true            
        );
        insert priceBook;
            
        Account acct = new Account(
            Name='Test Account',
            Price_Book__c=priceBook.Id, 
            NumberOfEmployees=20,
            Type='Customer'
        );
        insert acct;
            
        // Create a Product
        Product2 product = new Product2(
            Name = 'Example Product',
            Description = 'This is the Product description.',
            ProductCode = 'EX1234',
            StockKeepingUnit = 'EX5678',
            Family = 'Example Product Family',
            QuantityUnitOfMeasure = 'inches',
            DisplayUrl = 'https://www.example.com/',
            ExternalId = 'ID #1234',
            //UnitPrice=200,
            IsActive = true
        );
        insert product;

        // Insert the Product in the Standard Price Book (if necessary)
        PricebookEntry standardPriceBookEntry = new PricebookEntry(
            Pricebook2Id = Test.getStandardPricebookId(),
            Product2Id = product.Id,
            UnitPrice = 100.00,
            UseStandardPrice = false,
            IsActive = true
        );
        insert standardPriceBookEntry;

        // Insert the Product in the New Price Book
        PricebookEntry priceBookEntry = new PricebookEntry(
            Pricebook2Id = priceBook.Id,
            Product2Id = product.Id,
            UnitPrice = 100.00,
            UseStandardPrice = false,
            IsActive = true
        );
        insert priceBookEntry;

        PopulateStage__c popStage = new PopulateStage__c(
            Stage__c = 'Closed');
        insert popStage;
        
        Opportunity oppTemplate = new Opportunity(
            Name='Opportunity Template',
            //StageName=popStage.Stage__c,
            StageName = 'Closed',
            PopulateFromTemplate__c = false,
            CloseDate=System.today().addMonths(1),
            AccountId=acct.Id,
            Pricebook2Id=priceBook.Id,
            Product_Families__c='Salesforce Marketing Cloud',
            RecordTypeId=Schema.SObjectType.Opportunity.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().get('Opportunity_Template').getRecordTypeId()
        );
        insert oppTemplate;

        OpportunityLineItem cloneOpportunityLineItem = new OpportunityLineItem(
            OpportunityID=oppTemplate.Id,
            Quantity= 1,
            UnitPrice=1,
            Description='Prueba',
            Product2Id=product.Id,
            PricebookEntryId=pricebookEntry.Id);
        insert cloneOpportunityLineItem;  
        
        Project__c project = new Project__c(
            Name = 'name',
            Scope__c = 'scope',
            Key__c = 'KEY');
        insert project;
        
        Opportunity opp = new Opportunity(
            Name='Opportunity',
            CloseDate=System.today().addMonths(1),
            AccountId=acct.Id,
            Product_Families__c='Salesforce Marketing Cloud',
            Pricebook2Id=pricebook.Id,
            OpportunityTemplate__c=oppTemplate.Id,
            RecordTypeId='0125e000000hn8jAAA',
            JiraProjectKey__c = 'ASDF',
            PopulateFromTemplate__c = false,
            StageName = popStage.Stage__c,
            Project__c = project.Id);
        insert opp;
    }
    
    @isTest static void  getOpportunityTemplateFromOpportunity() {    
        Opportunity opp = [SELECT Id,Name,Product_Families__c,Pricebook2Id,RecordTypeId,Clarification__c,Footer__c,OpportunityTemplate__c, StageName, PopulateFromTemplate__c FROM Opportunity WHERE RecordTypeId='0125e000000hn8jAAA' LIMIT 1];

        // Perform test
        Opportunity opportunityTemplate = OpportunityTriggerHandler.getOpportunityTemplateFromOpportunity(opp);
        System.assert(opportunityTemplate != null);
    }

    @isTest static void  TestGetOpportunitiesTemplatesFromOpportunity() {    
        Opportunity opp = [SELECT Id,Name,Product_Families__c,Pricebook2Id,RecordTypeId,Clarification__c,Footer__c,OpportunityTemplate__c, StageName, PopulateFromTemplate__c FROM Opportunity WHERE RecordTypeId='0125e000000hn8jAAA'  LIMIT 1];
        
        // Perform test
        List<Opportunity> opportunityTemplates = OpportunityTriggerHandler.getOpportunitiesTemplatesFromOpportunity(opp);
        System.assert(opportunityTemplates.size() >= 0);
    }

    @isTest static void  TestGetOpportunityLineItemsFromTemplates(){
        Opportunity opp = [SELECT Id,Name,Product_Families__c,Pricebook2Id,RecordTypeId,Clarification__c,Footer__c,OpportunityTemplate__c, StageName, PopulateFromTemplate__c  FROM Opportunity WHERE RecordTypeId='0125e000000hn8jAAA' LIMIT 1];

        // Perform test
        List<Opportunity> opportunityTemplates = OpportunityTriggerHandler.getOpportunitiesTemplatesFromOpportunity(opp);
        List<OpportunityLineItem> opportunityLineItems = OpportunityTriggerHandler.getOpportunityLineItemsFromTemplates(opportunityTemplates);     
        System.assert(opportunityTemplates.size() >= 0);
    }
    
    @isTest static void  TestGetOpportunityLineItemsFromTemplate(){
        Opportunity opp = [SELECT Id,Name,Product_Families__c,Pricebook2Id,RecordTypeId,OpportunityTemplate__c,Clarification__c,Footer__c, StageName, PopulateFromTemplate__c  FROM Opportunity WHERE RecordTypeId='0125e000000hn8jAAA' LIMIT 1];

        // Perform test
        List<OpportunityLineItem> opportunityLineItems = OpportunityTriggerHandler.getOpportunityLineItemsFromTemplate(opp.OpportunityTemplate__c);     
        System.assert(opportunityLineItems.size() >= 0);
    }

    @isTest static void  TestCreateQuoteFromOpportunityLineItems() {
                Opportunity opp = [SELECT Id,Name,Product_Families__c,Pricebook2Id,RecordTypeId,Clarification__c,Footer__c,OpportunityTemplate__c, StageName, PopulateFromTemplate__c  FROM Opportunity  WHERE RecordTypeId='0125e000000hn8jAAA' LIMIT 1];

              Opportunity opportunityTemplate = OpportunityTriggerHandler.getOpportunityTemplateFromOpportunity(opp);

        // Perform test
        List<Opportunity> opportunityTemplates = OpportunityTriggerHandler.getOpportunitiesTemplatesFromOpportunity(opp);
        List<OpportunityLineItem> opportunityLineItems = OpportunityTriggerHandler.getOpportunityLineItemsFromTemplates(opportunityTemplates);
        OpportunityTriggerHandler.createQuoteFromOpportunityLineItems(opportunityLineItems,opp,opportunityTemplate);
        System.assert(opportunityTemplates.size() >= 0);
    }

    @isTest static void  TestAddOpportunityLineItems() {
        Opportunity opp = [SELECT Id,Name,Product_Families__c,Pricebook2Id,RecordTypeId,Clarification__c,Footer__c,OpportunityTemplate__c, StageName, PopulateFromTemplate__c FROM Opportunity WHERE RecordTypeId='0125e000000hn8jAAA' LIMIT 1];

        //Opportunity opp = [SELECT Id,Name,Product_Families__c,Pricebook2Id,RecordTypeId FROM Opportunity WHERE Name='ProContacto | Marketing Cloud | USD1250' LIMIT 1].get(0);
        Opportunity opportunityTemplate = OpportunityTriggerHandler.getOpportunityTemplateFromOpportunity(opp);
        //OpportunityTriggerPopulateFromTemplate
        List<Opportunity> opportunityTemplates = OpportunityTriggerHandler.getOpportunitiesTemplatesFromOpportunity(opp);
        List<OpportunityLineItem> opportunityLineItems = OpportunityTriggerHandler.getOpportunityLineItemsFromTemplates(opportunityTemplates);
        OpportunityTriggerHandler.createQuoteFromOpportunityLineItems(opportunityLineItems,opp,opportunityTemplate);
        OpportunityTriggerHandler.addOpportunityLineItems(opportunityLineItems,opp);
        System.assert(opportunityTemplates.size() >= 0);
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The golden rule of unit testing is ***you only gain coverage for code executed as part of a test method***.

You're missing coverage on your trigger. As it stands, none of your test methods are causing your trigger to be run. The only reason why you have any coverage for your trigger is because of your `@testSetup` method (which performs an `insert` on an Opportunity).

Since it's a template Opportunity, you're not entering the

```
if(opportunity.RecordTypeId != '0125e000000hxJtAAI' && opportunity.OpportunityTemplate__c != null && opportunity.StageName == popStage && opportunity.PopulateFromTemplate__c==true ){
```

block.

The bare minimum you'll need to do here is make an additional test method that inserts an opportunity that satisfies all of the conditions in that `if` statement.

The better approach would be to keep *all* of the logic in your trigger handler, which would mean moving everything inside of `if(Trigger.isInsert)` into your handler. Your trigger should only be responsible for calling your trigger handler.
Something like

```java
// The trigger is only responsible for getting you into the right part of
//   your handler
trigger MyTrigger on MyObject(afterInsert){
    if(Trigger.OperationType == System.TriggerOperation.AFTER_INSERT){
        MyTriggerHandler.afterInsert(trigger.new);
    }
}

public class MyTriggerHandler{
    // Your handler's DML methods are responsible for orchestrating the
    //   work you want to do
    public void afterInsert(List<MyObject> newList){
        for(MyObject record :newList){
            if(<conditions are met>){
                Opportunity template = getOpportunityTemplateFromOpportunity();
            }
        }
    }

    // Helper methods take care of (most of) the actual work
    public Opportunity getOpportunityTemplateFromOpportunity(){
        // do work
    }
}
```